# Project a smaller grid onto a bigger one

Tags: java, math, image-manipulation

I have been writing a image editing application for fun and all is well but i have ran into a problem with the zoom feature. The image editor plane is 512 x 512 pixels large but the image i want to edit is only 16 x 16. I want to know how to project my mouse coordinates to the smaller image to edit it pixel by pixel.

i have devised this algorithm to to such.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param pointx The x position of the point thats being bound
 * @param pointy The y position of the point thats being bound
 * @param oldsizeX The old grid size x of which the point is currently in. ( eg  ==> 512*512)
 * @param oldsizeY The old grid size y of which the point is currently in. ( eg 512* ==> 512)
 * @param newsizeX The new grid size x for the new grid size of the point. ( eg  ==> 16*16)
 * @param newsizeY The new grid size y for the new grid size of the point. ( eg 16* ==> 16)
 * @param normalOffsetX The offset x, if any, the grid has in the normal plane ( eg ==> 32*32 @ (512*512))
 * @param normalOffsetY The offset y, if any, the grid has in the normal plane ( eg 32* ==> 32 @ (512*512)
 * @return A Vector2 containing the bound points in the new plane.
 */
public static Vector2 bindPoint(int pointx, int pointy, int oldsizeX, int oldsizeY, int newsizeX, int newsizeY,int normalOffsetX,int normalOffsetY) {
    Vector2 vec = new Vector2();
    int tileSizeX = oldsizeX / newsizeX;
    int tileSizeY = oldsizeY / newsizeY;

    int offsetX = normalOffsetX, offsetY = normalOffsetY;

    vec.x = (int) (pointx / 2) / (oldsizeX / tileSizeX) - (offsetX / tileSizeX);
    vec.y = (int) (pointy / 2) / (oldsizeY / tileSizeY) - (offsetY / tileSizeY);

    if(pointx >= normalOffsetX && pointx <= normalOffsetX + oldsizeX && pointy >= normalOffsetY && pointy <= normalOffsetY + oldsizeY) {
        return vec;
    }else {
        return new Vector2(-1,-1);
    }
}
```

This works as long as the smaller resolution is 16x16 and i have found that if i change the 2 after the pointX and pointY division to 0.5 and an image of 32x32 works. What i want to know is if there is a better way to do so, so that i can use any size image at any zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `integers` to represent the position. Use `double` instead when you do the calculations. In the end, when you have calculated everything and need a pixel value, round the `double` to an `integer`. Otherwise you will have lose precision all over the place (which explains the problems you see).

You get different results depending on how you use your brackets. For example, from a math point of view the below `Systems out`'s should give you the same result, but they don't:

```
    int i = 700;
    int j = 70;
    int k = 30;
    System.out.println((i / 2) / (j / k)); --> 175
    System.out.println(i / 2 / j * k); --> 150
```

Comment: Its late and i was tired i figured it out wirh pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own lol, sorry, its late and i spaced and forgot how to proportion.

Here is the answer for anyone else who needs it!

```
/**
 * 
 * @param pointx The x position of the point thats being bound
 * @param pointy The y position of the point thats being bound
 * @param oldsizeX The old grid size x of which the point is currently in. ( eg  ==> 512*512)
 * @param oldsizeY The old grid size y of which the point is currently in. ( eg 512* ==> 512)
 * @param newsizeX The new grid size x for the new grid size of the point. ( eg  ==> 16*16)
 * @param newsizeY The new grid size y for the new grid size of the point. ( eg 16* ==> 16)
 * @param normalOffsetX The offset x, if any, the grid has in the normal plane ( eg ==> 32*32 @ (512*512))
 * @param normalOffsetY The offset y, if any, the grid has in the normal plane ( eg 32* ==> 32 @ (512*512)
 * @return A Vector2 containing the bound points in the new plane.
 */
public static Vector2 bindPoint(int pointx, int pointy, int oldsizeX, int oldsizeY, int newsizeX, int newsizeY,int normalOffsetX,int normalOffsetY) {
    Vector2 vec = new Vector2();
    int tileSizeX = oldsizeX / newsizeX;
    int tileSizeY = oldsizeY / newsizeY;
    int offsetX = normalOffsetX, offsetY = normalOffsetY;

    vec.x = (int) Math.floor(pointx * ((float) newsizeX) / (float) oldsizeX) - (offsetX / tileSizeX);
    vec.y = (int) Math.floor(pointy * ((float) newsizeY) / (float) oldsizeY) - (offsetY / tileSizeY);
    return vec;
}
```